# Shopping cart: adding more items into the cart array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, shopping-cart

How can I add more than one items into a shopping cart?

This is the html form,

```
<form action="cart.php?action=add" method="post" id="form-cart">
    <input type="text" name="cart[unique_id]" value="<?php echo $product->unique_id;?>" size="3" maxlength="3" />
    <input type="text" name="cart[quantity_stock]" value="<?php echo $product->in_stock;?>" size="3" maxlength="3" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
</form>
```

this is the `add_item` method in the `cart` class,

```
 public function add_item($info)
{

    # Check if the content array does not exist yet.
    if (isset($this->content[0]['unique_id'])) 
    {
        $i = 0;
        $this->content[$i]['unique_id'] = $this->content[$i]['unique_id'];
        $this->content[$i]['quantity_request']++;
        $this->content[$i]['quantity_stock'] = $this->content[$i]['quantity_stock'];
        $this->content[$i]['time_created'] = time();
        $i += $i;

        # Check if the quantity request exceeds quanity in stock.
        if($this->content[$i]['quantity_request'] > $this->content[$i]['quantity_stock'])
        {
            # If it does, then set the quantity request to quanity in stock.
            $this->content[$i] = array(
                'unique_id' => $this->content[$i]['unique_id'], 
                'quantity_request' => $this->content[$i]['quantity_stock'], 
                'quantity_stock' => $this->content[$i]['quantity_stock'],
                'time_created' => time(),
                'error' => 'The quantity you requested on this item is exceeding the quantity in our stock.'
            );
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        //$this->content[$unique_id] = array('quantity_request' => 1, 'quantity_stock' => $this->content[$unique_id]['quantity_stock'],'time_created' => time());

        # Create the content array, $unique_id as the key.
        # If it does, then set the quantity request to quanity in stock.
        $this->content[0] = array(
            'unique_id' => $info['unique_id'],
            'quantity_request' => 1,
            'quantity_stock' => $info['quantity_stock'],
            'time_created' => time()
        );
    }

}
```

So, after I have an item already in the class,

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'unique_id' => string '1386638969582999' (length=16)
      'quantity_request' => int 1
      'quantity_stock' => string '10' (length=2)
      'time_created' => int 1322429496
```

The array should have increased another item when I submit another item like this,

html,

```
<form action="cart.php?action=add" method="post" id="form-cart">
    <input type="text" name="cart[<?php echo $product->unique_id;?>][quantity_stock]" value="<?php echo $product->in_stock;?>" size="3" maxlength="3" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
</form>
```

php,

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'unique_id' => string '1386638969582999' (length=16)
      'quantity_request' => int 1
      'quantity_stock' => string '11' (length=2)
      'time_created' => int 1322429496

  1 => 
    array
      'unique_id' => string '1386638969582900' (length=16)
      'quantity_request' => int 1
      'quantity_stock' => string '10' (length=2)
      'time_created' => int 1322429400
```

But I always get one item only with the increasing requested quantity,

```
array
      0 => 
        array
          'unique_id' => string '1386638969582999' (length=16)
          'quantity_request' => int 2
          'quantity_stock' => string '10' (length=2)
          'time_created' => int 1322429496
```

Note that it now became **2** in `'quantity_request' => int 2`

The `quantity_request` should only increased if the same `unique_id` is clicked again.

How can I make this right?

**EDIT:**

html,

```
<form action="cart.php?action=add" method="post" id="form-cart">
    <input type="text" name="cart[<?php echo $product->unique_id;?>][quantity_stock]" value="<?php echo $product->in_stock;?>" size="3" maxlength="3" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
</form>
```

php,

```
public function add_item($item_array)
    {

        foreach ($item_array as $unique_id => $info)
        {

            # Check if the content array does not exist yet.
            if (isset($this->content[$unique_id])) 
            {
                $this->content[$unique_id]['quantity_request']++;
                $this->content[$unique_id]['quantity_stock'] = $this->content[$unique_id]['quantity_stock'];
                $this->content[$unique_id]['time_created'] = time();

                # Check if the quantity request exceeds quanity in stock.
                if($this->content[$unique_id]['quantity_request'] > $this->content[$unique_id]['quantity_stock'])
                {
                    # If it does, then set the quantity request to quanity in stock.
                    $this->content[$unique_id] = array(
                        'quantity_request' => $this->content[$unique_id]['quantity_stock'], 
                        'quantity_stock' => $this->content[$unique_id]['quantity_stock'],
                        'time_created' => time(),
                        'error' => 'The quantity you requested on this item is exceeding the quantity in our stock.'
                    );
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                //$this->content[$unique_id] = array('quantity_request' => 1, 'quantity_stock' => $this->content[$unique_id]['quantity_stock'],'time_created' => time());

                # Create the content array, $unique_id as the key.
                # If it does, then set the quantity request to quanity in stock.
                $this->content[$unique_id] = array(
                    'quantity_request' => 1,
                    'quantity_stock' => $info['quantity_stock'],
                    'time_created' => time()
                );
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You reset your $i to 0 at the start, thus making the $i++ irrelevant, so when you add another entry, it overwrites the old. Try $this->content[] so it just adds to the last.

Comment: Thanks. Then I get this error `Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in .. line 33` it refers to this line `$this->content[]['unique_id'] = $this->content[]['unique_id'];` I don't get it! :(

Comment: Ok I'll explain. You can only use [] for writing, it automatically writes to the overlast entry in php, but you DO need an index to read, since else it has no clue what to read. What you can do is create a variabele $i, outside the function, and use it as global, then use the $i as index and $i++ whenever you need to. That line of code also does absolutely nothing in your original code, since it practically says var = var; What do you try to achieve exactly? Think of that.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. see my answer above.